# xpath to capture form action attribute in php

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following form tag in my html source

```
<form class="webform-submission-form webform-submission-add-form webform-submission-footer-subscription-form webform-submission-footer-subscription-add-form webform-submission-footer-subscription-node-7-form webform-submission-footer-subscription-node-7-add-form js-webform-details-toggle webform-details-toggle" data-drupal-selector="webform-submission-footer-subscription-node-7-add-form" action="/en/" method="post" id="webform-submission-footer-subscription-node-7-add-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and I would like to capture the `action` value with xpath

this is what I've tried

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$link = $xpath->query('//form/a');
$link->getAttribute('action');
```

getting nothing in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$form = $xpath->query('//form'); // get the form (remove the "/a" you had)
$formAttribute = $form->getAttribute('action'); // your action is now stored in the $formAttribute variable
```

Comment: You can also select attributes in XPath with `//form/@action`